# Trying to force a method to wait for another method to end

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, objective-c-blocks

I have a method that's giving me some problems. I'm trying to execute two methods one after the other, but the second method keeps starting before the first one has finished. I'm fairly certain it has to do with the fact that there is a block in the first method, but as i do not understand them very well, I have been unable to fix it or even make use of other answers on here. Any help or advice would be really appreciated!

top-level method:

```
- (IBAction)SendTextTapped:(id)sender{
  NSLog(@"Entered tapped method");
  [self setLocation];
  NSLog(@"Supposedly past setLocation");
  [self sendInAppSMS:globalLocation];
  }
```

first helper method:

```
- (void)setLocation{
  CLLocation *location = locationManager.location;
  CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
  CLLocation *newerLocation =[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:location.coordinate.latitude
                                                       longitude:location.coordinate.longitude];
  NSLog(@"%f",location.coordinate.longitude);
  [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newerLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
      NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
      return;
    }
    //NSLog(@"Entered geocoder");

    if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
      CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];

      NSDictionary *addressDictionary =
      placemark.addressDictionary;

      NSLog(@"%@ ", addressDictionary);
      NSString *address = [addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
      globalLocation=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pickup: %@, %@\n person: Joe Blow", address,placemark.subLocality];
      NSLog(globalLocation);
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});
    }
  }];

}
```

second helper method:

```
-(void) sendInAppSMS:(NSString *)message
{
  NSLog(@"Entered sendInAppSMS");
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = message;
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"123456", nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

It all works fine when I have all the code in one method, but to continue with my project I need to be able to separate out the actions.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call that like so:

```
[self setLocationWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *message) {
    [self sendInAppSMS:message];
}];
```

Convert you method to this:

```
- (void)setLocationCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *message))completionHandler{
    ....
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (completionHandler) completionHandler(globalLocation);
    });
}
```

Comment: i just tried this, and it is not working either. Something strange is being passed to message in the sendInAppSMS method: <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x2223a620>